# Функция len golang символами UTF-8

Tags: golang

```
package main
import "fmt"
// import "unsafe"

func main() {
    word := string("крен")
    // lastSymb := string(word[len(word)-1])
    // fmt.Println(lastSymb)
    // fmt.Println(word)
    // fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(word))
    fmt.Println(len(word))
}
```

Началось с того, что я  не мог взять последний символ у русского слова, оказывается, многие источники неверно трактуют возвращаемое значение функции len() ,видимо переводят с английского,в котором все буквы попадают в классическую ASCII.ВНИМАНИЕ функция возвращает длину строки в БАЙТАХ, а не в символах.
Вопросы такие:

1. Почему возвращает 8 для слова крен, а не 10, где же символ конца строки?
2. Какой есть элегантный способ получать длину ЛЮБОЙ строки в символах?

UPD Нашел с использованием либы  "unicode/utf8" , но неужели мне надо притягивать целую либу просто для такого простого действия???Есть другие варианты?

Comment: о каком символе конца строки речь?

Comment: В кодировке [utf8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)  старшие 5 бит первого байта символа задают размер этого символа в байтах

Comment: @avp всего два варианта :) использовать готовую библиотеку или руками реализовать ее функциональность :)

Comment: @Grundy, смотря что из всей функциональности нужно. Если нужен подсчет длины строки  в символах utf-8, то всего-то  нужен статический массив из 32 маленьких чисел. Впрочем, вероятно я не прав и к этому массиву нужно добавить еще некоторую изобретательность, способность оценивать красоту и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @avp, не понял, а зачем массив из 32х чисел?

Comment: @Grundy, а вы хотите упаковать эти 32 числа в одно 64-битное? Тоже можно, но операций по извлечению длины (ведь каждое такое число это длина utf8-символа) будет больше. (если же вопрос про 32, то это поскольку 5 упомянутых выше бит кодируют 32 разных числа (это индексы вмассиве возможных длин (они от 1 до 4))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`len` возвращает число элементов в массиве или мапе. Тип string *по определению* это массив байтов фиксированной длины. Поэтому `len(word)` возвращает 8 байтов - ровно столько занимает представление слова `крен` в utf-8. В go строки НЕ zero-terminated, поэтому len возвращает 8, а не 9.

Буквы в go представляются типом `rune`. Для string определено специальное приведение типов `[]rune()`, которое возвращает массив букв строки (32-х битных символов UCS -2)

Приведение к массиву букв включает разбор байтовых последовательностей и запись 4х байтовых рун в память. Функция [`utf8.RuneCountInString`](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#RuneCountInString) подсчитывает юникодные символы без записи в память. Поэтому, если вам нужно только число символов, эта функция будет быстрее, чем `len([]rune(txt))`.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    txt := "крен"
    fmt.Println("len:", len(txt))
    fmt.Println("len([]rune):", len([]rune(txt)))
    fmt.Println("Rune count", utf8.RuneCountInString(txt))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/mYbjJpMeRDz

UPD

Последний символ можно добыть двумя способами - полным перекодированием в массив юникодных символов (ака `[]rune`) и декодированием только последнего символа

```
    // первый способ - конвертировать в последовательность юникодных символов
    runes := []rune(txt)
    lastRune := runes[len(runes)-1]
    fmt.Println("последняя буква: ", string(lastRune))
    // второй способ - читать байты с конца, пока не получится валидный utf-8
    decodedLastRune, _ := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(txt)
    fmt.Println("последняя буква: ", string(decodedLastRune))
```

https://go.dev/play/p/e071vJRW-gk

Comment: lastSymb := string(word[len(word)-2 : len(word)]) 
Беру последний символ вот так тогда, а есть какой-то более аккуратный спопсоб?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher добавил про последний символ

Comment: Спасибо большое